# Cocoapods - How to add an offline dependancy?

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, cocoapods, sqlcipher

I'm currently using the `Swift SQLite` code (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) to perform SQLite databases queries in my Swift code. This library is working perfectly but my problem is that I now want to use this code with ciphered databases... The documentation says that I just have to include a dependancy like showed after but I can't as I'm working on an offline computer (that can't be connected to Internet...).

```
target 'YourAppTargetName' do
    pod 'SQLite.swift/SQLCipher', '~> 0.12.0'
end
```

Does someone know a way to add an offline Cocoapods dependancy in my project (I could download code from Internet and transfer it via an USB key) ? Or is there an other way to use SQLCipher with this Github project ?

Comment: You can clone/download the project, and use local path in your `Podfile`. Cf https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#using-the-files-from-a-folder-local-to-the-machine

Comment: What should be the name of the ```Podfile``` ? I don't think I created a cocoapods application...

Comment: Go ton `~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release`, find `SQLite.swift`. Check that there is the SQLCipher code. Copy/Paste it in your Project folder (or download it from the Internet on another computer).. Replace  `pod 'SQLite.swift` (which you currently have) with  `pod 'SQLite.swift/SQLCipher', :path => "RelativePathToPasterProject/SQLite.swift.podspec"` and run a pod install

Comment: I don't have any Podfile yet, but I can create one this is not a problem. My SQlite dependancy has been resolved by cloning the Github and adding a swift package manager dependancy. Do I have to run ```pod install``` after these steps ?

Comment: So you installed it with SPM? Might have been a dog idea to say it. I checked the Package.swift (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Package.swift) and it seems to includes already the Cipher files, which were initially removed from the default PodSpec with `ss.exclude_files = 'Sources/**/Cipher.swift'`. Don't you see them already?

Comment: The ```Cipher.swift``` is indeed in the package (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Sources/SQLite/Extensions/Cipher.swift), but I don't have access to the added methods like ```key()``` for example... The thing is this method is calling a C method which belongs to the SQLCipher package isn't it ?

Comment: I checked, that's because the SPM doesn't have the Compile flag set to allow it. I don't know yet how to force it. I tried (replication the podspec specificties), but I didn't got a result.

Comment: I'll try to force them by adding these flags in the Xcode settings and I'll let you know !